# Do you need to pay taxes on income paid outside the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, non-resident

Non american here. I currently work in a country outside the US in Country A. I have a company training for 10 weeks coming up that is in the US office. During the time, I will be getting paid the same salary in Country A's local currency paid to my Country A bank account.

My question is, do I need to pay the US taxable income on the salary that I make during my stay in the US?

Comment: Are you an 'US person' (not a _US citizen_, a _**US person**_). That probably depends on your visa status, and is the major deciding fact.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are not US citizen or tax payer. 
Your visa is a business visa, then there is no taxes applicable for you.